# Which namespace from the .NET Framework should I research?

Tags: c#, .net

I am just beginning to play around with .NET (using C#).

Which namespace, aside from System.*, do I need to research ?

UPDATE: A number of people are asking why research namespaces.
My previous programming experience is mainly non-OOP and VBA (self-taught). 
I have no idea at all to what has already been provided in the .NET framework.
I don't want to sit down and write string-handling functions (for example) to then find out that all the string-handling I could ever need is already written for me (and works better than mine)

Comment: Related: [287927](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287927/best-way-to-learn-c)

Comment: Why do you think System.* is so important? What will you use the language for?

Comment: @mizipzor: I cannot think of a program that I would write that would not use System.* at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you want to start with namespace?

**Rather start with windows form applications, web apps, database operations.**

While working on these applications, you will need the details of required namespaces and classes.

At that time you can look int only required namespace.

Comment: Agree. Im a strong believer in learning by doing so just "researching" an arbitrary namespace wouldnt yield that much. Do stuff! The namespaces will come naturally.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether it makes sense to try to research on whole namespaces. They are large and it could get boring...

**My best way to dive into new frameworks or languages is examples**.

Try to achieve something specific (e.g. create a simple web shop, a hello world winforms app, ...). For that, google on how to do that. While studying the code examples answering your specific problems, you will get to know the object model without even noticing.

**You could also start with some tutorial**. Or, if you like books, **buy a book and read it**. Namespaces, however, I do not even care about what namespace provides a certain class. I just right-click the class and choose "Resolve".

Some tutorials:

- http://www.w3schools.com/ngws/default.asp
- http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=377&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1
- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/jmukharjee/WindowsFormsTutorial111282005011245AM/WindowsFormsTutorial1.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think you would benefit a lot more by reading over the source from a few decent applications than you will from researching a namespace. Of course, that largely depends on what you're trying to do - if you just want academic knowledge of C#, then that may be a solid direction. But if you want to actually build something, I would look at samples.

BabySmash is an interesting WPF app: http://babysmash.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/17438

Speaking of, Scott Hanselman did a long series called "[The Weekly Source Code](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CategoryView.aspx?category=Source+Code&page=4)" where he blogged about numerous open source projects whose source he was reading - to be a better developer. Most of those are C#.

Answer (score 0):

```
using Microsoft;
```

And there are many others on the internet, you'll find some good one on [CodePlex](http://codeplex.com), or write your own.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be start with the System.IO (Deep understanding of IO, reading and writing files, streams, etc).

For an "academic" vision of the framework read this book:

- [http://www.amazon.com/MCTS-Self-Paced-Training-Exam-70-536/dp/0735622779](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735622779)

Greetings ;)

Comment: 70-536 is fine if you're going to take the test. But for learning C# at an academic level, I would much prefer to read through [C# In Depth](http://www.manning.com/skeet/).

Answer (score 0):

This reminds of [DNR](http://www.dotnetrocks.com/) episodes, where they have a namespace or a class to be the thing of the day - much like the letter of the day on Sesame Street.

Seriously though, researching a namespace in language framework will not give you much practical knowledge. Far better to trawl through online tutorials and give yourself a mini project to work on.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to research into Namespaces, then `Microsoft` and `System` are the only places you really need to go. Whithin the System namespace you should check out:

- `System.Collections`
- `System.Data`
- `System.Linq`
- `System.Web` (If you're interested in ASP.NET)

There are of course many others, but these are the main ones for starting out. You can check out [MDSN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/) for more info on these.

I agree with most of the others answers though in the fact that really you should just read a book or do some web tutorials (check out [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/) again). Its the way I learnt and it worked just fine, although I suppose it will not suit everybody.